# Python strange bitwise and (&) output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

While using bitwise and operator (&) in my code I observed a strange behavior of python shell. While `10 and 10` gives 10 but `010 & 010` gives 8. These series follows for all the numbers with 0 in front like 011, 012, etc

Also, till 07 & 07 it works but 08 and 09 give a syntax error.

In python 3 we can't use 0 before a number altogether. Not able to understand is it an expected behavior or one of the python "wats".

Comment: thanks! its a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers entered with a leading zero are interpreted as octal (base 8).

```
007 == 7
010 == 8
011 == 9
```